# Don't know how to use/initialize struct functions

Tags: c, function, struct

I don't know how to use struct functions. I have declared the function as follows:

```
    struct persona buscarPersona(struct persona agenda[], int capacidad, char 
    nombre[]);
```

And want to use it in the switch case statement:

```
    case'3':
        printf("Buscar persona\n");
        struct persona buscarPersona(struct persona agenda[],int capacidad,char nombre[]);
        break;
```

Unfortunately, the function is not working, When 3 is pressed the function doesn't respond, I have encountered multiple problems when getting the main program to function due to initializing the function

Any advice to further understand my problem and come to a valid solution is more than welcome

Thank you

Comment: You're not calling the function in the switch statement - you're declaring it again.

Comment: Trying to lean C by trial&error is know to cause depressions.

Comment: What do you want that line to do?

Comment: @alk Getting lean in C is pretty hard, learning is more like bulking in terms of code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the function - not declare it again

```
  case'3':
        printf("Buscar persona\n");
        person = buscarPersona(agenda,42,name);
        break;
```

you need to have setup agenda, name  etc